# C# to VB.Net - HexString

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a Program from c# to vb.net and everything worked fine.
There is now 1 line of code left that I cant seem to convert over to VB.Net.
Would be awesome if someone could help me out with this.

C# Code:

```
if (num2 > 9)
            {
                text += ((char)(num2 - 10 + 65)).ToString();
            }
```

This is how I tried it:

```
If num2 > 9 Then
            text += CChar((num2 - 10 + 65)).ToString()
        End If
```

For "num2 - 10 + 65" It gives me the Error Code:

> "Integer Values can not be converted to Char"

.

what did I do wrong?

**Update:**
I fixed it myself by just changing CChar to Chr. Thats it.

Fixed Code:

```
 If num2 > 9 Then
            text += Chr(num2 - 10 + 65).ToString()
 End If
```

Comment: Depending on the rest of the code, you might be able to use `yourNumber.ToString("X")` to take advantage of the [hexadecimal format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#hexadecimal-format-specifier-x).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write that C# code in a less language-specific way would be like so:

```cs
if (num2 > 9)
{
    text += Convert.ToChar(num2 - 10 + 65);
}
```

You should not have any issue converting that to VB. Mind you, you should use the actual concatenation operator (&) in VB, rather than the addition operator (+). They behave the same way in many cases but not all.

```vb
If num2 > 9 Then
    text &= Convert.ToChar(num2 - 10 + 65)
End If
```

The `ToString` call is pointless because you can concatenate a `Char` with a `String`.

Comment: In C# it should be `if (num2 > 9) text += (char)(num2 - 10 + 65);`. In VB.Net, besides what you've already written, could be `If num2 > 9 Then text &= ChrW(num2 - 10 + 65)`

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Basic `+=` is `&=` and you need to convert your parameter to string, so change the line to

```
text &= CChar(Convert.ToChar(num2 - 10 + 65)).ToString()
```

Comment: *"you need to convert your parameter to string"*. No you don't. The concatenation operator will work with any fundamental type as long as one of the operands is a `String`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The parameter I'm talking about is the parameter passed to CChar. That needs to be converted into a String according to the docs, kindly look at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vb-net-language/0596000928/re31.html

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Actually, "CChar" will not give you the same result as the original C# code (try a few examples in both C# and VB to see what I mean). You need to use ChrW or Convert.ToChar.